# Remove n number of elements from object

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

i have a object like

```
obj = {name:"xxx" , des1:"x",des2:"xx",des3:"xxx" , age:"12"}.
```

But the property of des can be incresed as `des1,des2,des3,des4 ...` according to the users inputs. So basically we don't know how much of "des" properties are there in the object.

I want do something like this. Grab all the properties of `des` and `put` them in array. Then update the object as follows

```
obj = {name:"xxx" , description:["x","xx","xxx"] , age:"12"}
```

how can I achieve this using `ES6 syntax`

Answer (score 1):

you can transform your data in this way:

```
const transformed = Object.keys(obj).reduce(
(acc, key) => {
  return key === 'name' || key === 'age'
    ? { ...acc, [key]: obj[key] }
    : { ...acc, description: [...acc.description, obj[key]] }
},
{ description: [] }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this one?

```
const f = {name:"xxx", des1:"x", des2:"xx", des3:"xxx", age:"12"};

const { name, age, ...rest} = f;
const result = { name, age, description: Object.values(rest) };

console.log(result) // { name: 'xxx', age: '12', description: [ 'x', 'xx', 'xxx' ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `reduce` and then match the `string` with the regex which checks if the string is `des`, followed by a number

```js
var obj = {name:"xxx" , des1:"x",des2:"xx",des3:"xxx" , age:"12"}
const res = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key)=> {
   if(key.match(/^des([0-9]+)$/)) {
      if(acc.description) {
         acc.description.push(obj[key]);
      } else {
         acc.description = [obj[key]];
      } 
   } else {
      acc[key] = obj[key];
   }
   return acc;
}, {})

console.log(res);
```